# Windows 32x64 custom Program files folder

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, 64-bit

I am running Windows(8.1) 32 bit and I have my disc partitioned to several logical discs. 1 for OS, 1 for data and 1 for applications. Haven't been able to find answer to my question: Can I do the same partitioning with Windows 64? Are there any known problems with that? What about the fact, Windows 64 use 2 program files folders, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wont be a problem for the OS and most programs I know of. I do a similar thing with my system, and asside from me forgetting where it is at, I have not had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can have limited number of primary partitions (4 in windows),
but the limit for Logical partition is in 3-digit-figure

you only need 2 primary partition basically if you are installing windows 8 
1. for Bootloader (the one sized 350 MB)
2. Windows Partition

rest could be logical parition.

so to answer your question with x64, it won't be a problem

Comment: This answer only is valid if the user is using MBR, UEFI, does not have this limitation.